# Setting up JNDI connection with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, database-connection, jndi

I'm trying to set up a JNDI database connection for my WAR file which will be deployed on WebLogic 12c. This is what I have:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws DataSourceLookupFailureException {
  JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();

  return dataSourceLookup.getDataSource("jndiName");
}
```

In the `application.properties` file:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=jndiName
```

This is pieced together from two different sections of the Spring Boot guide:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-configure-a-datasource

I am confused, why is `jndiName` stated twice? Am I following correctly - is this the correct way to set up?

I am of the impression that Spring Boot will either automatically retrieve the JNDI name from `application.properties`, so that I do not need to hardcode the JNDI name into `getDataSource()`, or if I hardcode the JNDI name in then I wouldn't need to include that property in `application.properties` in the first place.

From my interpretation, the two sections of the guide covering how to set up a JNDI connection appear to contradict each other. What am I getting wrong? What exactly is the correct way to set this up?

Comment: This isn't the correct way. Just specify the JNDI name in the `application.properties` and Spring Boot will do the lookup. remove your own lookup. You either not both (unless you have multiple datasources you will have to find another way). The section you are pointing at is about configuring a custom datasource which is when the default configuration options don't give what you need.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm new to this, so please bear with me. So are you saying that the entire `dataSource()` is unnecessary? All I need is that one-liner in `application.properties`? Also, is there anything else that is required to be inside the file in order for it to be valid for use?

Comment: No that basically is all you need, the entry in `application.properties`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your custom bean and use application.properties but in local environment if you want to run embedded container this approach won't work

To use H2 or any other database in embedded container define profile in main method and then configure your data source. This way it works both in local and production